# Store blob/base64 in database and get it back as image with a async and await tx.executeSql React Native

Tags: react-native, sqlite, asynchronous, async-await, insert

i need to store a blob or base64 image object into sqlite database as blob datatype, and after reading the table i have to display the Image.

The only problem right now is, that i only get the bas64/blob object with await and async, but the insert statement do not let me await the return of the base64/blob conversition.

i can't get it into the database. If i use await in exeSql i have an empty table and if i store without await, its not working eather.

can anyone help me out?

EDIT:
This is my sql insert code:
i got  -> []  empty array as result
`db.transaction(async(tx) => { result.map(async(item) => { tx.executeSql( "INSERT INTO markets (name,imgUrl,done) VALUES (?,?,?)", [ item.name, await convertImageToBase64(item.imgUrl), item.done], (tx, results) => { console.log("Results", results.rowsAffected); }, (error) => { console.log(error); } ); }); });`

if i replace this `await convertImageToBase64(item.imgUrl)` with a string, everything works fine.
Somehow i can'T use await here.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to what you want to do. I am storing the image as Blob in SQlite database from my android app and retrieving it back as an image in my activity. I have used byte[] to store the data and its working fine. No need of await/async. Please go thru' the code.

```
public class DbBitmapUtility {
// convert from bitmap to byte array
public static byte[] getBytes(BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, stream);
    byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
    return image;
}

// convert from byte array to bitmap
public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}

public static boolean hasImage(Resources resources, @NonNull ImageView view) {
    boolean hasImage = false;
    Drawable drawable = view.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.ic_profile_pic);

    if(drawable != null) {
        if ((drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) && (!((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap().sameAs(bitmap))) {
           // hasImage = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap() != null;
            hasImage = true;
        }
    }

    return hasImage;
}
```

}

And for inserting the data into the table,

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(STUDENT_NAME, studentName);
    values.put(STUDENT_PICTURE, studentPicture);
database = getWritableDatabase();
    database.insert(TABLE_PERSONAL_INFO, null, values);
database.close();
```

And for conversion,

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imgStudent.getDrawable();
    byte[] image = DbBitmapUtility.getBytes(bitmapDrawable);
```

AND

```
Bitmap bitmap = DbBitmapUtility.getImage(studentPicture);
        imgStudent.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Let me know if it helps!